# 400 (Bad Request) on a get request which parameter its a url

Tags: javascript, .net, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to execute a get request with a parameter, the parameter its actually a string, but the string is a url

so I get this error:

```
react-adal.js:50 OPTIONS https://abc-app.azurewebsites.net/api/Page/https://abcde.sharepoint.com/sites/Site1 400 (Bad Request)
```

My script is like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Row, Col, Tabs, Menu, Dropdown, Button, Icon, message } from 'antd';
import PageHeader from '../../components/utility/pageHeader';
import Box from '../../components/utility/box';
import LayoutWrapper from '../../components/utility/layoutWrapper';
import ContentHolder from '../../components/utility/contentHolder';
import basicStyle from '../../settings/basicStyle';
import IntlMessages from '../../components/utility/intlMessages';
import { Cascader } from 'antd';
import { adalApiFetch } from '../../adalConfig';


export default class extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {options:[]};
        this.loadData = this.loadData.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        adalApiFetch(fetch, "/SiteCollection", {})
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(json => {
            console.log(json);
            const firstLevelOptions = json.map(post => ({
                value: post.Url,
                label: post.Title,
                isLeaf: false    
            }));

            this.setState({
                options: firstLevelOptions
            });
          });
    }

    onChange = (value, selectedOptions) => {
        console.log("value:", value, "selectedOptions", selectedOptions);
    }

    loadData = (selectedOptions) => {
        console.log("loaddata", selectedOptions);

        const targetOption = selectedOptions[selectedOptions.length - 1];
        targetOption.loading = true;

        const options = {
            method: 'get',
              headers: {
                      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
              }                    
          };

        adalApiFetch(fetch, "/Page/"+targetOption.value, options)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(json => {
            targetOption.loading = false;
            console.log(json);
            const secondLevelOptions = json.map(comment => ({
                value: comment.id,
                label: comment.body,
                isLeaf: true    
            }));
            targetOption.children = secondLevelOptions;
            this.setState({
                options: [...this.state.options],
            });
            }
        );

    };

    render(){
        const { rowStyle, colStyle, gutter } = basicStyle;
        const TabPane = Tabs.TabPane;

        return (
        <div>
            <LayoutWrapper>
            <PageHeader>{<IntlMessages id="pageTitles.PageAdministration" />}</PageHeader>
            <Row style={rowStyle} gutter={gutter} justify="start">
            <Col md={12} sm={12} xs={24} style={colStyle}>
                <Box
                title={<IntlMessages id="pageTitles.siteCollectionsTitle" />}
                subtitle={<IntlMessages id="pageTitles.siteCollectionsTitle" />}
                >
                <ContentHolder>
                    <Cascader
                                options={this.state.options}
                                loadData={this.loadData}
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                                changeOnSelect
                    />
                </ContentHolder>
                </Box>
            </Col>
            </Row>
        </LayoutWrapper>
        </div>
        );
  }
}
```

My web api code is like this:

```
 [Authorize]
    public class PageController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ListItemCollection> Get(string sitecollectionUrl)
        {
            var tenant = await TenantHelper.GetActiveTenant();
            var siteCollectionStore = CosmosStoreFactory.CreateForEntity<TenantManagementWebApi.Entities.SiteCollection>();
            await siteCollectionStore.RemoveAsync(x => x.Title != string.Empty); // Removes all the entities that match the criteria
            string domainUrl = tenant.TestSiteCollectionUrl;
            string tenantName = domainUrl.Split('.')[0];
            string tenantAdminUrl = tenantName + "-admin.sharepoint.com";

            KeyVaultHelper keyVaultHelper = new KeyVaultHelper();
            await keyVaultHelper.OnGetAsync(tenant.SecretIdentifier);

            using (var context = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager().GetSharePointOnlineAuthenticatedContextTenant(sitecollectionUrl, tenant.Email, keyVaultHelper.SecretValue))
            {
                var pagesLibrary = context.Web.GetPagesLibrary();
                CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(100);
                var pages = pagesLibrary.GetItems(query);
                return pages;

            };
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried url-encoding the URL parameter? I also assume that default convention based routing it being used. ie `api/{controller}/{id}`. Which could also cause problem as `sitecollectionUrl` wont match the `id` in the convention based route template.

Comment: Include the WebApiConfig for the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how the routing has been configured you could end up not matching the intended action.

Try using attribute routing on the server to have finer control of the route for that action.

Enable attribute routing in `WebApiConfig`

```
//attribute routing
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

//convention-based routes
//...
```

Update the ApiController to use a catch-all parameter

```
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("api/Page")]
public class PageController : ApiController {
    //GET api/Page/https://abcde.sharepoint.com/sites/Site1
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{*sitecollectionUrl}")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(string sitecollectionUrl) {
        var tenant = await TenantHelper.GetActiveTenant();
        var siteCollectionStore = CosmosStoreFactory.CreateForEntity<TenantManagementWebApi.Entities.SiteCollection>();
        await siteCollectionStore.RemoveAsync(x => x.Title != string.Empty); // Removes all the entities that match the criteria
        string domainUrl = tenant.TestSiteCollectionUrl;
        string tenantName = domainUrl.Split('.')[0];
        string tenantAdminUrl = tenantName + "-admin.sharepoint.com";

        KeyVaultHelper keyVaultHelper = new KeyVaultHelper();
        await keyVaultHelper.OnGetAsync(tenant.SecretIdentifier);

        using (var context = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager().GetSharePointOnlineAuthenticatedContextTenant(sitecollectionUrl, tenant.Email, keyVaultHelper.SecretValue)) {
            var pagesLibrary = context.Web.GetPagesLibrary();
            CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(100);
            var pages = pagesLibrary.GetItems(query);
            return Ok(pages);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this didnt make any effect, I still get bad request, maybe I am missing something on the client side?

Comment: @LuisValencia what you originally had worked when you removed the scheme? Or are you saying what I have works when you remove the scheme?

Comment: what you told me works, if I remove the scheme from the parameter

Comment: @LuisValencia if all else fails you can go the query string route like `adalApiFetch(fetch, "/Page?sitecollectionUrl="+encodeURIComponent(targetOption.value), options)`

Answer (score 2):

You must encode the URL you are sending as a parameter when calling your api:

```
adalApiFetch(fetch, "/Page/"+encodeURIComponent(targetOption.value), options)
```

And probably you will need to decode it on your backend.

Comment: is there a difference with encodeURIComponent? because I tried this and had the same error.

Comment: that doesnt work, and encodeURIComponent doesnt work either, it does not even get to the web api, breakpoint is never hit

Comment: Sorry, it should be `encodeURIComponent(url)`. I have tested on a nodeJS backend and it works. And I didn't need to decode, when I got the parameter from URL it was already decoded.

Comment: @LuisValencia is it still giving bad request or has it now changed to not found? Now that the url has been fixed you need to take the route template into consideration. Check second half of my comment on the original question.

Comment: still same bad request error, I tried both EncodeURI end EncodeURIComponent, I attacked a remote debugger to my azure instance and it never hits the first line.

Comment: I've never used Azure before, but I would guess that your instance is refusing requests because the port is not opened. Have you checked if the port is open?

Comment: it has nothing to do, all other requests works perfect.